# Mongoose Change Streams and Front End Integration

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I'm currently working with data such that two users may be using concurrently. I need User B's app page to render the changes User A made to the data after he/she saves it to the database. I figured I could use mongoose's change stream functionality to accomplish this.

**Backend**: Express, MongoDB

**Integration**: Axios

**Frontend**: React.js with Redux

I know how to call to the back end from the front end by sending a get/post/put request through Axios, but I don't know how to send data to the front end without an API call.

Example code

```
const listenToData = async () => {
    Person.watch().on('change', data => {
        //callback function: what to do here to send changes to the front end?
    }
}
```

Would the above code go in my API? Would it go in the Redux Actions of the front end? What do I do after the 'on change' event is triggered to send the new data to the front end of the user? Is there a way I can broadcast the event to the front end and take care of it there?

Is change streams not enough, will I need something like WebSocket?

Comment: Could you do that? I'm trying to do the same! And I can't find any solution! Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure it out after this time? I'm trying too